# sqlsrv_num_rows() returning -1

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm running a stored procedure with sqlsrv_prepare(), while running same stored procedure directly onto the database I can see that there are rows returned. But running with sqlsrv_prepare() and checking no of rows returned via sqlsrv_num_rows() I get -1 returned.

```
function getSOLAIndexCheckReleaseStatusCount() {
        global $dbConnection, $SOLAIndexCheckReleaseStatus;
        $dbConnection= dbConnectSolaReplicaDBServer();

$query = "exec [SolaQC].[dbo].[sp_BinaryQC_IndexCheckReleaseStatus]";

        $params = array();
        $options =  array( "Scrollable" => 'buffered',"QueryTimeout" => 480);

$result = sqlsrv_prepare( $dbConnection, $query,$params,$options);
        if( $result === false ) {
            //die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            die("Something didn't go too smoothly! Try refreshing?");
        }
        $output = "";
        if (!sqlsrv_execute($result)) {
            //echo "Your code is fail!";
            die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
        if ($result) {
            $check_empty = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
            if ($check_empty == true) {
                $output.= sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
            }
            else {
                $output.= sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
            }
        }
return $output;
    }
```

Below is the expected results:

[image]

I am not sure why sqlsrv_num_rows() doesn't return result in PHP. Can someone point me in the right direction?

FYI - I am using Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1a PHP/7.3.0

Comment: It's just a guess, but if you miss `SET NOCOUNT ON` as a first line in your procedure, you'll receive multiple result sets. Then `sqlsrv_num_rows()` may return the rows from first rowset - this with informational message.

Comment: @Zhorov thanks for the input. yes, that was the problem. After, adding SET NOCOUNT ON - PHP is fetching final resultset fine and displaying count of rows perfectly. Again thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be an issue with the last if statement. You can check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php) a documentation about the function you are using..

Comment: $check_empty = sqlsrv_has_rows($result);
            if ($check_empty == true) {
                $output.= sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
            }
            else {
                $output.= sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
            }

Comment: don't get what you referring to me..I've already checked that link and tried whats on it.